# How to open React-Bootstrap Modal component (child modal) on top of the parent modal component while also hiding the parent modal?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I was successful in opening a child modal on top of another parent modal using React-Bootstrap. But, I also want to hide the parent modal after I open the child modal. But, when I trigger the parent modal using React-Bootstrap `handleClose` method to close it, the child modal `handleClose` method is also triggered. That makes the child modal close too. Is there a way to handle this problem?

In the below picture, I have the child modal on top of parent modal which is working for now. But, I want the parent modal to hide.

[image]

Comment: You haven't shared any code so it's a bit difficult to point out why it's happening. However here's a working demo where the parent modal hides and the child modal appears. When the child modal is closed, the parent modal reappears: https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-react-bootstrap-in-react-app-ytuhdc?file=index.js